# ProcessPoolExecutor using a function which is supposed to append to a list not working properly

Tags: python, multiprocessing, append, concurrent.futures

I'm starting to use Python for forecasting coming from R, and I bumped into this problem while trying to estimate multiple models using multiprocessing. I'm trying to estimate a same model (ARIMA) with multiple combinations of parameters, and had success doing it using a for-loop. However, I was trying to apply multiprocessing to increase efficiency, and I'm having some issues.

This is the function I'm trying to run:

```
arima_comp = []

def arima_tester(p,q,P,Q):
    mod = ARIMA(training_set, order = (p,1,q), seasonal_order = (P,1,Q,12))
    modfit = mod.fit()
    forecast = modfit.forecast(steps = len(test_set))
    error = forecast - test_set 
    rmse = np.square(error).mean() ** 0.5
    aic = modfit.aic
    model = "ARIMA("+str(p)+",1,"+str(q)+")"+"("+str(P)+",1,"+str(Q)+")[12]: "
    arima_comp.append(
        {
            "Modelo":model,
            "AIC":aic,
            "RMSE":rmse
        }
    )
```

The idea was to estimate multiple combinations of models and append all of them to this `arima_comp` list, in order to compare them aftwerwards. It worked fine with the for-loop, but when I run the `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map` as follows:

```
pq_aux = [0,1,2,3]
PQ_aux = [0,1]

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(arima_tester, pq_aux, pq_aux, PQ_aux, PQ_aux)
```

It seems as if the function was not executed, because if I call the `arima_comp` list, it returns me an empty list:

```
arima_comp
#Returns []
```

Do any of you have any idea what am I doing wrong? It's not as if I'm receiving an error when I run this code, I just don't get the expected result. Thank you in advance.

I expected the same result as if I ran a for-loop over the function for different combinations of `p,q,P,Q` in the `arima_tester` function, the it would append to `arima_comp` list, giving me something like that:

```
arima_tester(0,0,0,0)
arima_tester(0,0,0,1)
arima_tester(0,0,1,1)
arima_comp


#Returns:[{'Modelo': 'ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,0)[12]: ',
  'AIC': 1198.2900239812564,
  'RMSE': 6.653975098794921},
 {'Modelo': 'ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,1,1)[12]: ',
  'AIC': 1127.5935159029652,
  'RMSE': 7.400152967890038},
 {'Modelo': 'ARIMA(0,1,0)(1,1,1)[12]: ',
  'AIC': 1125.0164173629523,
  'RMSE': 7.996184118574912}]
```

**UPDATE**

I just followed the answers below, and now I'm getting a "BrokenProcessPool" error. A minimal, reproducible example that leads (at least for me) to the very same error can be found below:

```
import concurrent.futures

def function(a,b,c,d):
    sum = a+b+c+d
    halfsum = sum/2
    squaredsum = a ** 2 + b ** 2 + c ** 2 + d ** 2
    return {
        "Sum":sum,
        "Sum Divided by 2":halfsum,
        "Squared Sum": squaredsum
    }

ab_values = [0,1,2,3]
cd_values = [0,1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        final_list = list(executor.map(function, ab_values, ab_values, cd_values, cd_values))
```

Whenever I run this code I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BrokenProcessPool                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 6
      4 if __name__ == '__main__':
      5     with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
----> 6         final_list = list(executor.map(function, ab_values, ab_values, cd_values, cd_values))

File c:\Users\lfval\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py:570, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists(iterable)
    564 def _chain_from_iterable_of_lists(iterable):
    565     """
    566     Specialized implementation of itertools.chain.from_iterable.
    567     Each item in *iterable* should be a list.  This function is
    568     careful not to keep references to yielded objects.
    569     """
--> 570     for element in iterable:
    571         element.reverse()
    572         while element:

File c:\Users\lfval\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py:621, in Executor.map..result_iterator()
    618 while fs:
    619     # Careful not to keep a reference to the popped future
    620     if timeout is None:
--> 621         yield _result_or_cancel(fs.pop())
    622     else:
    623         yield _result_or_cancel(fs.pop(), end_time - time.monotonic())

File c:\Users\lfval\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py:319, in _result_or_cancel(***failed resolving arguments***)
    317 try:
    318     try:
--> 319         return fut.result(timeout)
    320     finally:
    321         fut.cancel()

File c:\Users\lfval\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py:458, in Future.result(self, timeout)
    456     raise CancelledError()
    457 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 458     return self.__get_result()
    459 else:
    460     raise TimeoutError()

File c:\Users\lfval\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py:403, in Future.__get_result(self)
    401 if self._exception:
    402     try:
--> 403         raise self._exception
    404     finally:
    405         # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception
    406         self = None
```

I'm trying to run this code on Windows 10 using Python 3.10.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list to which you are trying to append to, `arima_comp`, is defined at global scope. When you create your processing pool, each process, which is running in its own address space (one of characteristics that distinguished multiprocessing from multithreading) will be appending to *its own copy* of `arima_comp`. That is, this list is not sharable across processes. Thus when all the tasks submitted to the pool complete, the copy of `arima_comp` that exists in the main process's address will still be empty since it was never modified.

The simplest solution is to:

1. Remove `arima_comp` altogether and have `arima_tester` *return* the dictionary it was previously appending to `arima_comp`.

```py
def arima_tester(p,q,P,Q):
    ... # Unmodified code omitted for brevity
    return {
        "Modelo":model,
        "AIC":aic,
        "RMSE":rmse
    }
```

2. The `ProcessPoolExecutor.map` function you are calling actually returns an *iterator* that can be iterated to retrieve successive return values from `arima_tester`. Thus you just need the following minor code change:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    arima_comp = list(executor.map(arima_tester, pq_aux, pq_aux, PQ_aux, PQ_aux))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer to the problem and your explanation, it was very clear. However, now I'm facing the 'BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.' problem. I've tried adding 'if __name__' on top, but it does not seem to be working...

Comment: You need to update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and stack trace that duplicates the error you are getting. Also, tag your question with the platform you are on (Linux? Windows? Home-brewed? etc.). Let me know when you have done so.

Comment: I just updated the question with a similar example of what I'm trying to do. I also posted the full error alongside it.

Comment: Your `cd_values` list is shorter than your `ab_values` list (2 elements vs. 4 elements). According to the documentation on the built-in `map` function, which applies here also, **With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.** On my Windows 10, Python 3.8.5, this runs to completion but only 2 tasks will be submitted as if  you coded `ab_values = [0,1]` .  I am not sure why yours fails. Try making the two lists the same length, although I am doubtful that will make a difference.